# Why doesn't border color work with value inherit?

Tags: css

Why doesn't the `p` tag inherit the border color?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
p {
  border: 1px dashed inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)

> Only the individual properties values can inherit. As missing values are replaced by their initial value, it is impossible to allow inheritance of individual properties by omitting them. The keyword inherit can be applied to a property, but only as a whole, not as a keyword for one value or another. That means that the only way to make some specific value to be inherited is to use the longhand property with the keyword inherit.

So use longhand properties for inheritance instead.

Answer (score 6):

No, this won't work. You can however set the separate properties and then inherit the color, like the following:

```
div {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

p {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: While that does work, *why* does it work? Why isn't the `border-color` property allowed/respected in the shorthand syntax, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: You are correct, the other answer should be marked as an answer. :) I actually learned why myself today.

Comment: @DavidThomas, this is due to the shorthand property having a default border-color value. I encountered this issue while setting up some theme switching. 

Timon's solution worked for me.

Here's some reading on the matter:
1. [MDN Border property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) 
2. [MDN Shorthand information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)
3. [CSS Shorthand Syntax Considered an Anti-Pattern](https://csswizardry.com/2016/12/css-shorthand-syntax-considered-an-anti-pattern/) by CSSWizardry